# UWP fluent design in XamarinForms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, fluent-design, acrylic-material

I'm creating a XamarinFroms solution and i want to implement Fluent Design or pats of it in my UWP app. As you may know, Most of Fluent Design building blocks are ThemeResources. so i tried to do:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush"))
            {
                var brush = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush"] as AcrylicBrush;
                var tint = brush.TintColor;
                var opacity = brush.TintOpacity;
                var fallbackColor = brush.FallbackColor;
                var source = brush.BackgroundSource;
            }
```

but unfortionalty i get a

```
System.Exception: 'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))' on the brush creating line of code.
```

I won't be able to access any predefined Brushes or i can never implement reveal styles if i'm not able to retrieve those theme resources in code in my UWP project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UWP fluent design, it is only available in UWP, you could not implement it within xamarin Forms directly. Currently Xamarin Forms has not provided such interface. =Because it is specific design for UWP. And it is hardly to abstract a unified interface that available for each platform. So the better way is implement this with Custom Renderer separately. For example, as in your case, to make `SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush` work in Xamarin.UWP, you could custom `LayoutRenderer`. And the following segment code realize `AcrylicWindowBrush` for `StackLayout`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StackLayout), typeof(ICustomStackLayoutRenderer))]

namespace CustomStackLayoutRenderer.UWP
{
    public class ICustomStackLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Layout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

        }
        protected override void UpdateBackgroundColor()
        {
            base.UpdateBackgroundColor();
            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush"))
            {
                var brush = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush"] as AcrylicBrush;
                var tint = brush.TintColor;
                var opacity = brush.TintOpacity;
                var fallbackColor = brush.FallbackColor;
                var source = brush.BackgroundSource;
                this.Background = brush;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually i extracted the provided code from a custom renderer. Of course in order to implement Fluent Design in UWP through XF is using a custom renderer or an effect. The question was about the error i get when i attempt to access  the ThemeResource

Comment: The same code woks in my side. Have tested in other computer?

Comment: Now i don't get that exception. It would be very helpful if you explained why i was getting it

Comment: emm, I guess it may be that the compiler is not loading resources causing this issue.

Comment: That really helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'm developing a UWP app and having the same issue in the UWP app at runtime, whenever I try to access `App.Resources`. It says: ": 'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))'". P.S. there are no resources defined at all, but I get this error anyway.